# Determine the range of ${\rm i}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}$ on $\left\{f\in L^2([0,1]):f\text{ is absolutely continuous and }f(0)=f(1)=0\right\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, operator-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $\operatorname{AC}(0,1)$ denote the space of absolutely continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb C$, $$Af:={\rm i}f'\;\;\;\text{for }f\in\mathcal D(A):=\left\{f\in L^2([0,1];\mathbb C):f\in\operatorname{AC}(0,1)\text{ and }f(0)=f(1)=0\right\}.$$

> How can we determine the range $\mathcal R(A)$ of $A$?

I've read that $$\mathcal R(A)=\left\{g\in L^2([0,1];\mathbb C):\int_0^1g=0\right\},$$ but I absolutely don't understand why this equality holds. (Maybe we need to redefine $\mathcal D(A)$ such that $f'\in L^2((0,1))$ for all $f\in\mathcal D(A)$.) It the description of the range is totally wrong, how can we determine it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the range is not correct. If $f(x)=(1-x)\sqrt x$ then it is easy to see that $if' \notin L^{2}$ even though $f$ is AC and vanishes at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Do you know what's the range instead?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't think there is a simple description of  the rang e. However, the domain is usually taken as $\{f\in L^{2}: f \text {is AC},f' \in L^{2}\}$. If you take this as the domain then the description of the range given in the question is correct.

Comment: I think that this is the domain I actually wanted to consider in the first place. How do we see that the description of the range in the question is correct with this domain?

Comment: With this new domain take any $g \in L^{2}$ with $\int_0^{1} g(T)dt=0$. Define $f(x)=-i\int_0^{x} g(t)dt$. Then $f $ is in the domain of $A$ and $Af=g$. (The indefinite integral of any integrable function is AC).

Comment: If $f\in L^2([0,1],\mathbb C)\cap C^\infty([0,1],\mathbb C)$, does it automatically follow that $f'\in L^2([0,1],\mathbb C)$? (Your example in the question is not a counterexample, since that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.)

Comment: I don't think so, since your $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ and hence $f\not\in C^\infty([0,1],\mathbb C)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I misread your comment. Any continuous function  on $[0,1]$ belongs to $L^{2}$. If $f$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function then $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, sure. You're right.

Comment: So, if we consider $A$ on the different domains $\mathcal D_1(A):=\left\{f\in L^2([0,1];\mathbb C):f\in\operatorname{AC}(0,1)\text{ with }f'\in L^2([0,1];\mathbb C)\text{ and }f(0)=f(1)=0\right\}$ and $\mathcal D_2(A):=\left\{f\in L^2([0,1];\mathbb C):f\in\operatorname{AC}(0,1)\text{ with }f'\in L^2([0,1];\mathbb C)\text{ and }f(0)=f(1)\right\}$, the range of both should be the same, i.e. $A\mathcal D_1(A)=A\mathcal D_2(A)=\mathcal R(A)$, right? Or am I missing something?